# Firefox plugin update

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have the source code from a plugin for second life to play in a browser but the problem is it's been created for Firefox 3.5, so what I'm trying to do is to bring it up to speed and upgrade it to the current Firefox.

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to go about this as I am literally just looking into this now, any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What's your main aim here? Are you interested in simply making the extension work somehow in the latest firefox or are you more interested in optimizing performance?

Optimization of an application is a very general topic. You can look into the upgrades [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko) has gone through in the recent versions. If there seems to be any specific module for which Gecko is now offering a better interface/compatibility, you might try adapting the same. Again, this is really the programmer's judgment and skill which lets him draw the boundary between feasible and non-feasible development. For a module which is extensively linked with many other modules, it might be a good idea to leave it as it is to avoid sleepless nights (of course that's just my opinion. For some, that is the real kick :D).

If you are interested in creating high-performance plugins, you might like to give [Google Web Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) a try. It is a Java library which compiles java into optimized javascript introducing various performance oriented quirks. I understand that it is not possible to switch an entire application to GWT easily and wouldn't help you just now, but I think it is worth mentioning for future use.

On the other hand, if you are just interested in making the extension work, you may look into [Nightly Tester Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nightly-tester-tools/), which is an extension used to override add on compatibility.

Comment: Ok what I'm trying to do exactly is use the REI in browser client for playing opensim worlds, I have the source code but as I pointed out it's for firefox 3.5 I want to edit the source code to make it compatible with recent firefox but don't even know where to begin